# Passing data from bootstrap modal form to main form

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a problem that I don't really know how to execute, I have this two forms one is on my parent page and shows the sales history of products and then have a form to input the quantity of products for the next months.
[Main page table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Ref.png)
Then I have a modal that follows the model of the main page but instead of individual products it tracks the quantity of products by product type. I want to pass the data that is in the modal form to the form fields in the parent page table input fields.
[Modal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNB1p.png)
(Note that both include roughtly the same fields product/product type name, quantities from past months up to last, then already paid this month, sold but not paid this month, avg from last 3 and 6 months, sum of paid+not paid this month, form of expeted quantities from this month until this month+6)

But how do I do this?

The in my context I have the list of products that I use to generate my parent page table with the form and the product type list that I use to generate the modal table. In the product list they have data as type that If i send the data from the modal I can use to match.

I'm using Django and bootstrap.

modal code snippet

```
 {% for family in families %}
                <tr id="family_1">
                        <th scope="row" class="text-uppercase">{{family.name}}</th>
                        <td class="text-center">KG</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.five_back}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.four_back}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.months_first}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.months_second}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.months_third}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.months_fourth}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{family.wallet}}</td>
                        <td id="med3_mst" class="text-center">{{family.med3}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">346</td>
                        <td class="text-center">0</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <input id="prvs_m0" type="text" class="form-control input-td border-0 bg-danger bg-opacity-25">
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input id="prvs_ck_m0" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <input id="prvs_m1" type="text" class="form-control input-td border-0 bg-warning bg-opacity-25">
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input id="prvs_ck_m1" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

main page code snippet

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr id="{{ product.code }}" name="{{product.code}}">
      <td scope="row">{{ product.origin_sale }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.code }}</td>
      <td>
        {{ product.name }}
...
<td class="text-center">
              <input type="number" 
              class="form-control input-td border-0 bg-opacity-10" 
              style="background-color: white" id = "{{ product.code }}_forecast_m0" 
              name="forecast_m0" 
              value="{{product.current_month}}" 
              min="{{product.limitmin}}"
              max="{{product.limitmax}}" 
              onchange="updateInput(this.value, this.id, this.name, this.min, this.max)">
            </td>
```

So the idea is when I submit the form in the modal the main page inputs receives the values by the type of product (family) given that both the types have and ID that is in the product description in context.

Comment: It would be good if you re-edit your question and add the `view`, and the `html` code. Without those, it's merely impossible to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I can not give you specific instructions on how to execute this as I can't see the code you have.

It sounds like you have a modal that has a form and when the user submits that form, you need to access this data and use it somewhere else on the same page.
If you are using jQuery, then this can be done using the `.submit()` event to capture form submissions and the `.preventDefault()` method to prevent the default action of the form. Then inside the event feedback you can access the data you want from the fields you have and use this data to populate other areas in the page. You might also need to execute a function that closes the modal after you are done (Check the documentation of the modal you are using)

Example:

```
$( "#forminthemodal" ).submit(function( event ) {
   // Get data
   username = $("#usernamefieldid").val();

   // put data somewhere else:
   $("#div").text(username);

   // or use the data as the value of another field (input):
   $("#anotherinput").val(username);

   event.preventDefault();
});
```